# Story where music is played non-stop

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, music

I've been trying for a long time to remember the author and title of a short story I read many years ago about a society where there's non-stop music played everywhere - much like nowadays.  The main character objects to this constant barrage of noise and is consigned to a psychiatric hospital - which also has non-stop music - because he's considered to be crazy for wanting to live in silence.  Can anyone help me identify it?  Thanks.

Comment: How many years ago? Can you narrow it down to a decade or two?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't narrow it down to more than about late '50s/early '60s.  It may even be earlier than that.  I remember that I must have read it at the same time as I read Harrison Bergeron by Kurt Vonnegut (which was also driving me crazy because I couldn't remember what that was called or who wrote it either, I managed to find it after a LOT of googling). I'm almost sure they were both in an anthology of short stories of Science Fiction/Fantasy - but I've had a look through Kurt Vonnegut's output and I can't find anything like it and no amount of searching on my part has come up with it.

Answer (score 18):

I think this is Ray Bradbury's "[The Murderer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Murderer_%28story%29)":

> A psychologist exits the noisy environment to confront a patient confined to a small safe-room. The psychologist notes that the man has ripped the radio out of the wall to silence it. The room seems unnaturally quiet to the psychologist, yet the patient seems perfectly at ease, even happy.

Comment: BRILLIANT!!! That's the one!  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Sunflowers: When you return, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.