# A man on a bus wearing a wrist watch with which he could speak to his wife - short story by Ray Bradbury?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

That's all I can remember- I think it was a short story by Bradbury.  The funny part was that the man was in constant communication with his wife via his wrist phone.

Comment: Jeez, that's not different to real life brah!

Comment: Interesting story, could you check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if that helps jog your memory?

Comment: Yesterday,my daughter came to visit me. Something rang. It was her wristwatch. Her husband was calling and she andwered him through her wristwatch. I was astonished! I had never seen a device like that. It reminded me so much of a Ray Bradbury story I read years ago. How prescient he was! What in 1953 was totally science fiction is a reality today. (And equally as annoying!).

Answer (score 8):

Ray Bradbury's 1953 story "[The Murderer](http://www.sediment.uni-goettingen.de/staff/dunkl/zips/The-Murderer.pdf)" ([ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58409)):

> When it
> wasn't music, it was interoffice communications, and
> my horror chamber of a radio wristwatch on which my
> friends and my wife phoned every five minutes. What
> is there about such 'conveniences' that makes them so
> temptingly convenient? The average man thinks, Here
> I am, time on my hands, and there on my wrist is a
> wrist telephone, so why not just buzz old Joe up, eh?

....

> "But they went too far. If a little music and 'keeping in
> touch' was charming, they figured a lot would be ten
> times as charming. I went wild! I got home to find my
> wife hysterical. Why? Because she had been
> completely out of touch with me for half a day.
> Remember, I did a dance on my wrist radio? Well, that
> night I laid plans to murder my house."

Answer found by Googling `bradbury wrist phone`

Comment: And if confirmed, this is a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142356/23243 which was accepted by comment.