# Short story: Man on bus disrupting other passengers' communications

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

Short story: A man on a bus is observing passengers all talking on watch/phones, then electronically disrupts their communications.

Possibly a Ray Bradbury story.

Answer (score 17):

This is Ray Bradbury's [The Murderer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Murderer_(story))

> "Then  I got the idea of the portable diathermy machine. I rented
>   one, took it  on  the  bus  going  home that night. There sat all the
>   tired commuters with their wrist radios, talking to their wives,
>   saying, 'Now I'm at Forty-third, now I am at Forty-fourth, here I am
>   at Forty-ninth, now turning at Sixty-first.' One husband  cursing, 
>   'Well,  get  *out* of that bar, damn it, and get home and get dinner 
>   started,  I'm at Seventieth!' And the transit system radio playing
>   'Tales from the Vienna Woods,' a canary singing words about a
>   first-rate wheat cereal. Then  I  switched  on my diathermy! Static!
>   Interference! All wives cut off from husbands  grousing  about  a 
>   hard  day at the office. All husbands cut off from wives  who  had 
>   just  seen  their  children  break a window! The 'Vienna Woods'
>   chopped down, the canary mangled! *Silence!* A terrible, unexpected
>   silence. The bus  inhabitants  faced  with  having to converse with
>   each other. Panic! Sheer, animal panic!"
>
> "The police seized you?"
>
> "The  bus  *had*  to  stop.  After  all,  the  music *was* being scrambled,
>   husbands  and  wives  *were*  out  of touch with reality. Pandemonium, riot, and
>   chaos. Squirrels chattering in cages! A trouble unit arrived, triangulated on me
>   instantly,  had  me reprimanded, fined, and home, minus my diathermy machine, in
>   jig time."

Comment: He references the same concept in *Fahrenheit 451* in the subway scene with the “Denham’s Dentifice” ad. And I guess the “family” wall TVs are part of that theme. Hmmm.. maybe I should stop reading Stack Exchange and just get off the internet.

Comment: If confirmed, this is a duplicate of [this older question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141994/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor How can it be a duplicate if the OP uses a different scene to try and identify the story?

Comment: @Llewellyn Because of [our policy on story-ID duplicates](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31394).